# Strange Detachable Keyboard Behavior on NextBook NXW9QC132B tablet/netbook

Tags: linux, debian, usb, keyboard

I have this netbook with a detachable keyboard. It uses usb protocol over some springloaded pins.

For a reason that I can not figure, the detachable keyboard only works in Linux when you do the following steps:

- Plug in an external keyboard through micro usb otg
- Press power button to power on
- Wait for debian boot menu
- arrow (or use volume rocker) down to enter uefi settings
- detatchable keyboard now works and you can use it to continue boot

The keyboard and trackpad work just fine, and any devices plugged in the side of the keyboard are detected and work until...

When you unplug and re-plug-in the detatchable keyboard while debian is running, it does not work. There are no uevents in udevadm, nothing in dmesg, and nothing will change in lsusb. No trackpad, no keyboard, and nothing plugged into the side usb port (on the keyboard itself) is detected.

The only way to get any input at this point are via the touchscreen or a keyboard plugged in the micro-usb otg port.

I am wondering if there are any commands to try that could somehow force debian to try and detect this keyboard.

For clarification:

- NextBook NXW9QC132B
- Intel Atom 3735f

debian 32-bit (uefi is 32-bit, despite 64-bit processor)